# group list by last string of each line

Tags: command-line, sort, string, text-formatting

I'm having a list of strings (sorted IP address ranges) like this:

```
10.100.0.0-10.100.255.255 External: 2.2.2.2
10.120.0.0-10.255.255.255 External: 2.2.2.2
10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255 External: 3.3.3.3
192.168.160.1-192.168.160.255 External: 3.3.3.3
and so on..
```

How can I group these by the last string of each line so that the result would look similar to this:

```
External: 2.2.2.2
  10.100.0.0-10.100.255.255
  10.120.0.0-10.255.255.255

External: 3.3.3.3
  10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255
  192.168.160.1-192.168.160.255
```

Note: Handling of IP addresses is not required. We can treat these as strings as they are already sorted and ordered. I'm looking for a pure Bash solution (not Python) and preferably without xargs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the groups compact, i.e. are all of their members grouped together?

Comment: **Pure** bash, or are grep/awk/sed fair game?

Comment: grep/awk/sed are fully ok. all members are grouped together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember the last external ip in a variable. If the new ip is different, print the new one. Then print the ip range.

```
#! /bin/bash
last_ip=""
while read range _e ip ; do
    if [[ $ip != "$last_ip" ]] ; then
        printf '\nExternal: %s\n' "$ip"
    fi
    printf '  %s\n' "$range"
    last_ip=$ip
done < "$1"
```

Comment: +1 Precisely what I had in mind.  Only edit I would suggest is `\n` in front of `External:` as it appears the OP desires a blank line between groups.

Comment: @JimL. Thanks, updated. It's also possible to remove the newline from the very first line, but let's keep some work for the OP.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll try to bring that in line with my one-liner after all the sorts and greps already being in place.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{

if($2$3 in STORE){

##make column 2 and column 3 as key to store address.
STORE[$2$3]=STORE[$2$3]"\n""\t"$1  ##add new line here 

}
else{
##if key not in STORE, add first column with a tab 
STORE[$2$3]="\t"$1 

}
}
##print everything using END 

END{
for(add in STORE){
print add"\n"STORE[add]
}
}' file.txt
```